# Download Googlesheet using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I followed a tutorial about reading data from Google Sheet on (http://www.telerik.com/blogs/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android).

For the first time, everything works fine, but when I click on the button for the second time, the application crashes. (I'm running the app on a device with API level 17). The class looks as: public  class  DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask) {...}

Google says, a new instance of AsyncTask has to be created each time, which is considered in the tutorial. I tried many things, but none worked for me. May I please have your idea and solution for this problem. Thanks for your hlep in advance.

Comment: google also say : AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) , don't use it for downloading files , trust me

Comment: You're right, but this is a very light file which I use it for experiment. It runs with no issues for the first time and it displays the result very quickly. But if you click on the button again even after 1 hour, still the app will crash....

Comment: oh if it's a crash than add LogCat so we can help you , and also the code...